# Tires won’t come off rims

Tags: tire

Help!
Have a Diamondback Release with Schwalbe Hans Dampf tires on Blanchard rims.  Couldn’t break bead to get tires off as I wanted to convert to tubeless, even after trying tire levers for an hour with hot soapy water as a lubricant. In the end, I had to get a bike shop to do it for me.

Is this a common problem with these rims or tires.  This isn’t good.  What if you were trailside and needed to work on your tire? Is there a tire that would come off using your hands without having to take rims to dealer?

Comment: I tried for an hour even used hot soapy water on edges.ended up dropping them off at bike shop.

Comment: You may find this method of laying the wheel on the ground, standing on the tire & pulling up on the rim useful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Cs4y8K5hiU

Comment: Couldn’t get tyre levers in. Absolutely no room to get tires in.
Didn’t want to damage rims or tire

Comment: How did the shop do it ? more confident with tire levers ?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't fully deflate the tires.  It's usually best to remove the valve cores so that all the air can get out.

Comment: Shop around for tyre levers, since tubeless can be tough to mount or get off there are 'pinching' levers that press the sidewalls from both sides loosening them effectively from the rim-hooks.

Comment: @renesis has it.  Some tubeless rim/tyre combos are an insanely tight fit.  I first stumbled across the 'standing on it' method after 2hrs trying to break the bead on my WTB Trailblazers and almost breaking my thumbs instead.  I really have no idea what i'd have done had I punctured trailside in the cold/wet before I got them converted to tubeless.

Answer (score 5):

It may be that your rims are "tubeless ready" which means they have a lip around the side that the tyre slots into which makes an airtight seal but does make them harder to get off. You should be all right if you let the tyre down completely and then push the edges of it towards the centre with your thumbs to pull it out of the slot. Once a bit of it's free the rest will usually pull out easily.

Comment: Actually, never mind the lip at the side. Tubeless rims have a channel in the center. If the OP pushed the tire beads into that channel, the channel is deeper than the rim bed, and chances are it would have been easier to get the tire off. This is why it helps to push the tire into the center. Feel free to modify your answer to state this.

Answer (score 1):

Know this is an old post. Agree with everything. Just wanted to add another problem I ran into. Got one side's bead out. Couldn't get the other side out for the life of me. Nearly broke my thumbs trying to knead it out. Nothing.

Got a bright light to see what was going on. When the tire was installed, the rim strip must've gotten pushed over into rim seat with the other bead. Pulled the rim strip out and that bead was off like 30 seconds later. It was like too much material was crammed in there.

Comment: Good point - the rim strip can get in the way, or if its too wide can overlap both sides.   Welcome to the site and thank you for your contribution - do have a go at any other questions of interest, and also browse the [tour] for info on how the site is organised.